# C#で文字列を1つだけ分割する方法

Tags: c#

C#で、次のように文字列を分割すると、stArrayに5つの要素が入ります。

```
string testString = "a,b,c,d,e";
string[] strArray = testString.Split(',');
```

これを最初の','だけ分割して、"a"と"b,c,d,e"に分割して
"b,c,d,e"の部分だけ取得するにはどうしたら良いですか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[String.Split メソッド](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0#System_String_Split_System_Char___System_Int32_)を見ればわかりますが、複数のオーバーロードが用意されています。必要な機能を持つバージョンを選択してください。具体的には [`Split(Char[], Int32)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0#System_String_Split_System_Char___System_Int32_) が該当します。

---

なお、

> ```
> testString.Split(',');
> ```

とありますが、こちらは [`Split(Char[])`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0#System_String_Split_System_Char___) であり具体的には

```
public string[] Split (params char[]? separator);
```

という形式です。引数は `','` と記述していますが、C#コンパイラは [`params`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params) 指定を受けて引数を `new Char[1] { ',' }` と読み替えてコンパイルしています。

対して、 `Split(Char[], Int32)` は

```
public string[] Split (char[]? separator, int count);
```

という形式でこちらは `params` 指定がありません（`params`は最終引数にしか使えないため）。C#コンパイラは前述のような読み替えはありませんので、明示的に記述する必要があります。最終的には次のような記述になるかと思います。

```
var strArray = testString.Split(new []{ ',' }, 2);
```

---

> "b,c,d,e"の部分だけ取得するには

という質問に答えて `String.IndexOf` および `String.Substring` を組み合わせた回答が投稿されています。もちろんこれらも希望を満たす結果となっていますが、別アプローチも提案します。

正規表現を使用することで、条件を満たした文字列を抽出することができます。例えば

```
var m1 = Regex.Match(testString, "^(?:([^,]*),){1}(.*)");
```

と書けます。`m1`は次のような値が格納されます。

- `m1.Groups[1].Captures[0].Value` = `"a"`
- `m1.Groups[2].Value` = `"b,c,d,e"`

この方法ですと分割数を変更したくなった場合も簡単です。

```
var m2 = Regex.Match(testString, "^(?:([^,]*),){2}(.*)");
```

と変更すると`m2`は次のような値が格納されます。

- `m2.Groups[1].Captures[0].Value` = `"a"`
- `m2.Groups[1].Captures[1].Value` = `"b"`
- `m2.Groups[2].Value` = `"c,d,e"`

`String.IndexOf` ＋ `String.Substring` ではここまで柔軟な動作をさせることができません。

なおこの正規表現は手抜きをしていて改行が含まれていると正しく動作しません。

Comment: 質問の最後が`"b,c,d,e"の部分だけ取得するには`なので結果は配列ではなく単一の文字列が欲しいのでは？ だから「最終的には」の記述とするなら、最後に`[1]`を追加した方が良いと思われます。

Comment: 質問文は分割を行った `string[] strArray` を取得する部分までしかコードは書かれていません。後続のコードには `strArray[1]` 等の処理が続くと思われます。そこで質問の趣旨に沿い  `string[] strArray` に希望する結果を格納する処理を提示しました。

Comment: なるほど、タイトルの方を重視したわけですね。

Comment: @kunif それもありますがもう少し違った見方をしています。質問は２分割ですが、Q&Aの蓄積の観点ではそこを拡張してＮ分割可能な実装の方が応用が効きますので。

Comment: その辺は分かりますが、単なるバリエーション例を提示しただけのつもりなのに、もう一人の回答も含めて急なマイナス投票の集積でびっくりしました。

Comment: 単一の文字列でも、strArray[1]でもどちらでも取得できればどちらでも望み通りの結果ですのでおかげで無事解決いたしました。質問時に、単一の文字列を取得できる可能性も頭はよぎりましたが、言語仕様上、無理なく取得できればそれで大丈夫です。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

これでどうでしょうか？

```cs
string testString = "a,b,c,d,e";

// 最初の','の位置
int i = testString.IndexOf(',');

// 最初の位置より後を切り出す
string s = testString.Substring(i + 1);

// b,c,d,e
Console.WriteLine(s);
```